# Based vs unbased fibration: Fiber sequence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

My question is focused on basepoint issues in topology. The starting point is basically Problem 4.3.18 in Hatcher which asks us to show that a fibration sequence induces a long exact sequence after applying $\langle X, - \rangle$. I'm interested in:

> Let $F \xrightarrow{i} E \xrightarrow{p} B$ be a fibration, i.e. $F = p^{-1}(b_0)$ is a fiber for a chosen basepoint $b_0 \in B$. Then, the sequence of based sets $\langle X, F \rangle \to \langle X, E \rangle \to \langle X, B \rangle$ is exact for any topological space $X$.

So I'm confused about the basepoint here. I believe Hatcher wants $p$ to be an unbased fibration (because based fibrations never appear in his book). But I wonder if this result is even true in this generality for unbased fibrations - it feels weird for me to switch between unbased and based categories.

If I want to show $\ker{p_*} \subseteq \operatorname{im}{i_*}$, then I want to lift a homotopy but my proof breaks down since this homotopy needs not be basepoint-preserving. It appears that the result is true for well-pointed spaces $X$ because $p$ satisfies the based homotopy lifting property with respect to well-pointed spaces (see e.g. [Tyrone Cutler, Lemma 1.3](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Etcutler/pdf/Fibrations%20IV.pdf)). The same notes contain basically the same proof I'm suggesting for this result, only that everything is assumed to be in the based categories ([Tyrone Cutler, Proposition 1.6](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Etcutler/pdf/Fibrations%20IV.pdf)).

Does Hatcher tacitly mean that $p$ is a based fibration or that $X$ is a nice space or is there some technique that can make this work even in this generality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to say what Hatcher *really* means, unfortunately he isn't always precise in his formulations.

As far as I know we need a *pointed fibration* to get the eaxct sequence in your question. However, if you want to work with free fibrations $p : E \to B$, you can easily prove that for each *well-pointed*  $(X,x_0)$ you get an exact sequence
$$\langle (X,x_0), (F,e_0)\rangle \to \langle (X,x_0), (E,e_0)\rangle \to \langle (X,x_0), (B,b_0)\rangle$$

I guess this is what Hatcher has in mind since he mainly works with CW-complexes in Chapter 4 (he does not say anything explicitly about $X$).

Comment: Thank you, it's nice to have someone confirm my beliefs! (Note that I also mentioned the result for well-pointed spaces in my question.)